# Sign in of web application not working from IE11

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication, internet-explorer-11

I have developed an MVC4 web application that uses Forms Authentication and cookies.  In all browsers it has worked fine since I started (a couple of years).

I have now tried to test this site with IE11 from a microsoft virtual box and the login process does not work.  When I click login nothing happens and I am redirected back to the login page as if I wasn't authenticated.

At first I thought it was because the cookie was expiring however the cookie is being set as I can see it in the Temporary files.  My code does not seem to be doing anything tricky.

**NOTE:  When I added the site to Compatibility view the login process worked**

Here is the Login / Cookie code

```
public void SignIn(HttpResponseBase response, string userName, bool rememberMe)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userName)) 
          throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or empty.", "userName");

    var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                        1, 
                        userName, 
                        DateTime.Now, 
                        DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(FormsAuthentication.Timeout.TotalMinutes), 
                        rememberMe, 
                        string.Empty);

    var cookie = new HttpCookie(
                        FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, 
                        FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket));
    cookie.HttpOnly = true;

    if (rememberMe)
    {
        cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;
    }

    response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}
```

I have created a custom AuthorizeAttribute that that should just delegate up the chain as I am not making the sign in via ajax.

```
public class OverseerAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext context)
    {
        if (FormsAuthentication.IsEnabled)
        {
            if (context.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                context.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("REQUIRES_AUTH", "1");
                context.Result = new EmptyResult();
            }
            else
            {
                base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(context);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(context);
        }
    }
}
```

If I remove the AuthorizeAttribute from the controllers then the system attempts to login but it bombs out as it doesn't have a username.  When I put this back in nothing happens.

Answer (score 6):

Try using `cookieless="UseCookies"` attribute in the `forms` element of your web.config file. 
That should solve the problem. Read here for more information:

http://gyorgybalassy.wordpress.com/2013/09/23/aspnet-40-forms-authentication-issues-with-ie11/

Comment: Awesome thanks.  I can't look this week as on holiday but will give it a go as soon as I am back.