# Forms Authentication in IE 11

Tags: cookies, forms-authentication, internet-explorer-11

I am having a similar problem as the one referenced in:

[Sign in of web application not working from IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19552813/sign-in-of-web-application-not-working-from-ie11)

except my application is not written in MVC.  Everything works fine, except in IE 11, where in certain situations the Forms authentication fails and the user is sent to the Login page.  The answer give on the above post (and it seems the generally accepted "fix" for this IE 11 problem from other sites I have looked on) is to add cookieless="UseCookies" to the Forms tag in web.config...

Does adding cookieless="UseCookies" make the site accessible only to users who have cookies enabled? What about sites that do not want to be limited solely to users that accept cookies?  I tried using cookieless="AutoDetect" instead, but in IE 11 I still get some failures.

Answer (score 1):

We just encountered the same problem, and fixed it by adding `cookieless="UseCookies"`.  With this setting, your users will need to allow cookies in order to log in.  To whatever extent you can browse the site without logging in, that should still work for those not enabling cookies.